# Redirect ALL Urls ending with a word to its same URL without that ending word

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How to redirect ALL URLs via `.htaccess` so that ALL urls ending with `-text/` are redirected to `(url)/`, removing the `-text` part.

For example, ALL urls ( with word `-text/` ) :

```
https://www.example.com/example-text/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/example/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove `-text` at the end of the URL-path (before the final slash) you could do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file (before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section).

For example:

```
RewriteRule (.+)-text/$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

No other directives are required (since the `RewriteEngine On` directive is in the WordPress code block that follows).

The `$1` backreference (in the *substitution* string) contains the URL-path that precedes `-text/` at the end of the URL-path.

This applies to *any* URL that ends in `-text/`. If it should only apply to URLs that contain a single URL-path segment (as in your example), then you can modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern* as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)-text/$ /$1/ [R=302,L]
```

This will match `/example-text/` (single path segment) as before, but not `/foo/bar-text` (two path segments).

Note that these are 302 (temporary) redirects. If this is intended to be permanent then change it to a 301, but only once you have tested that it works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser by default so can make testing problematic.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! : ) /bow

Answer (score 0):

- This is not exactly your answer
- But I put this answer here so that maybe it will solve the problem of some other people

  ```
  function forward_to_url(){
   $self = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

   //The string you want to find
   $itemCheck = "url";
   $needle = $itemCheck. '/';

   //Any Address You want redirect
   $forwardlink = '/'.preg_replace('/'.strtolower($itemCheck).'/','',strtolower($self));

   $length = strlen($needle);
   $urlend= substr($self, -$length);

   if ($urlend == $needle or $urlend == $itemCheck) {
       wp_redirect($forwardlink, 301);
   }
  }
  add_action('template_redirect', 'forward_to_url');
  ```